# Android: Start activity from a MenuItem

Tags: android, menu

I'm new on Android, and I'm trying to start an Activity from a `MenuItem` choose of the user.

Actually, I'm building my menu (and is working OK) from my main activity class using a `MenuInflater`:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        //the Menu Inflater class allows to create a menu from a XML File
        MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menutest,menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And im handling the Menu selection using the following code (working fine too):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.MenuItemNewWebsite:
            ShowScreenAddSite();
        break;

        default:    
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a second and last activity called AddWebsite, and i would like to start it, but the following code doesnt work:

```
protected void ShowScreenAddSite()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(AddWebsite.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Do you know what is the extra thing that I have to pass to the `Intent` constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the solution was too simple, appears that in android, every activity class is not automatically referenced in the manifest.xml.

I just only add the new activity to the manifest, and works fine.

Regards.
Jose

Comment: Since this solved your problem you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still quite new to android myself but don't you need to be passing a context to the Intent constructor?

```
protected void ShowScreenAddSite()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, AddWebsite.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
```

You're probably doing this from inside an activity so I think you should be using 'this'

Comment: Hi Matt, 

Thanks for the response. 

I tryied this option, but i get an error saying that the application has finished unexpectly.

The code of my Addwebsite activity is the following (maybe there is anything wrong...):
public class AddWebsite extends Activity
{

  @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.screenaddsite);
     }
}
Do you see anything else weird in the code?
Thanks.
Best Regards.
Jose.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(this);
    final Intent[] menuIntents = new Intent[] {
              new Intent(this, AddWebsite.class) };
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    final int ms = menu.size();
    for (int i=0; i < ms; i++) {
        menu.getItem(i).setIntent(menuIntents[i]);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

avoiding some method calls, however you need to pay attention to the mapping between menu ids, menu order and intents but this is almost always known.